# Deploying nextjs/typescript app(express server) on aws beanstalk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js, web-deployment

I deployed one on heroku(with github pipeline) and it works perfect, but I can't do it on aws beanstalk. If it's not possible to do it with github, I'll be satisfied enough to do it with uploading local file bundle. Here's the code I upload on heroku, but can't upload on beanstalk. https://github.com/wiktorkujawa/cinema-manager

Update: I did it with local source bundle and it works.

Answer (score 0):

use code pipeline to streamline your deployment and attach the code pipeline to your EB deployment environment in the AWS Console Code Pipelines itself. If you are having problems while deploying check the Elastic Beanstalk console in the environments you should find logs that might help as well.